# ReWrite Rule Regular Expression Photobucket

Tags: url-rewriting

Since Photobucket have locked down 3rd party access

I have a simple way to fix

[IMG]http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y28/account/2016%20Lakes%20Tour/DSCF2570_zpsovyzw5c0.jpg[/IMG]

Need to become

[IMG]http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y28/account/2016%20Lakes%20Tour/DSCF2570_zpsovyzw5c0.jpg~original[/IMG]

So think a ReWite rule would sort here

my thoughs are match photbucket in url and .jpg[IMG], then ReWrite to add ~original

Thanks guys

Blue